# react-native-snap-carousel full screen + passing content

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a two part question. I'm currently using `react-native-snap-carousel` found here: https://github.com/meliorence/react-native-snap-carousel .

My code looks like this:

```
    carouselItems: [
        {
            image: require('../assets/images/placeholder-slide.png'),
        },
        {
            image: require('../assets/images/slide2.png'),
        },
        {
            //I want to pass <View> here with content and a button
        },
    ]

_renderItem({ item, index }) {
    <View>
        <Image source={item.image} />
    </View>
}
    
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.body}>
        <Carousel
            layout={"default"}
            ref={ref => this.carousel = ref}
            data={this.state.carouselItems}
            sliderWidth={phoneWidth}
            itemWidth={phoneWidth}
            renderItem={this._renderItem}
            inactiveSlideOpacity={1}
            inactiveSlideScale={1}
            slideStyle={{ width: phoneWidth }}
            onSnapToItem={index => this.setState({ activeIndex: index })} />   
    
    
        //This is the block I want to pass in the 3rd slide of the carousel 
        <View>
            <Text>Some Text Here</Text>
            <button>Button here</button>
        </View>
    </SafeAreaView>

body: {
    flex: 1,
    position: 'relative',
},
```

So the first two items in the carousel are a full-width image, the last slide will contain content and 2 buttons. How do I pass the items in the `<View>` into the `carouselItems`?

My second question is how do I make the carousel full screen. Here is a screenshot of my simulator: https://ibb.co/ZNZKRqm

As you can see there is grey area above and below the carousel. I don't believe this is something to do with the carousel, I think maybe by default this is full width? But I have seen applications target this gray space as well.

Comment: How does your `_renderItem` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Part

```
carouselItems: [
        {
            image: require('../assets/images/placeholder-slide.png'),
        },
        {
            image: require('../assets/images/slide2.png'),
        },
        {
            content:
<View>
            <Text>Some Text Here</Text>
            <button>Button here</button>
        </View>
        },
    ]

_renderItem({ item, index }) {
//return item.content if exists
   return item?.content || <View> 
        <Image source={item.image} />
    </View>
}
    
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.body}>
        <Carousel
            layout={"default"}
            ref={ref => this.carousel = ref}
            data={this.state.carouselItems}
            sliderWidth={phoneWidth}
            itemWidth={phoneWidth}
            renderItem={this._renderItem}
            inactiveSlideOpacity={1}
            inactiveSlideScale={1}
            slideStyle={{ width: phoneWidth }}
            onSnapToItem={index => this.setState({ activeIndex: index })} />   
    </SafeAreaView>
```

2. Part
   The grey space is because of the`SafeAreaView`. This will only be on the devices with a notch. You can set custom backgroundColor for it with a `style` prop.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try part 1 in about a half hour. If all is well i'll thumb it up! As for 2. Is there a way to have the carousel items leak into that area. So that it's not a background color in that area but instead the carousel image?

Comment: I think if you take out SafeAreView it will behave like that. And you can wrap the 3.screen with it, otherwise the text component won't be visible.